# Does encrypt time less than decrypt time in RSA cryptograohy?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, benchmarking, public-key-encryption

I going to do implementation RSA cryptography. I want know . How many times encryption faster than decryption in RSA cryptography. I try compute elapsed time in java by use System.currentTimeMillis(); but give me time encrypt = 0.05 ms while time decrypt 0.55 ms mean from that 1:11. I think this result is not rational my code is the follow

```
//here my key has 256 bits
 for (;;) {
            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            decrypt();
            }

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long time = end - begin;

            if (time >= 10000) {
                System.out.printf("Average Encryption takes: %.2f ms\n",
                        (double) time / num);
                break;
            }

            num *= 2;
        }

p = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, random);
q = BigInteger.probablePrime(128, random);
N = (p.subtract(one)).multiply(q.subtract(one));
e = BigInteger.probablePrime(32, random);
d = e.modInverse(N);

private void encrypt()
{
    C= M.modPow(e,N);
}

private void decrypt()
{
    RM = C.modPow(d, N);
}
```

please any explanation for these results

Comment: What's the value of "num"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why RSA Decryption process takes longer time than the Encryption process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316241/why-rsa-decryption-process-takes-longer-time-than-the-encryption-process)

Comment: Depending on the choice of `e` and `n` encryption will be perhaps 20 to 500 times as fast as decryption. In your case they're closer than normal size you chose a rather large `e` and a small `n`.

Answer (score 5):

Please, don't implement RSA yourself, it is very easy to do it wrong and it takes months to write version which will be resistant to 3-4 older cryptographic attacks.

[All the crypto code you’ve ever written is probably broken](http://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken) -- Tony Arcieri

[RSA encryption is more difficult. The 'best practice' in implementing RSA is: don't implement RSA. Other people have done it better than you can.](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic.html) -- Matthew Green (Johns Hopkins University)

[Why Cryptography Is Harder Than It Looks](http://www.schneier.com/essay-037.html) -- Bruce Schneier, 1997:

> Most systems are not designed and implemented in concert with cryptographers, but by engineers who thought of cryptography as just another component. It's not.

In industrial implementations of RSA, *encrypting using someone's public key is faster* then decrypting using private key, because public key has **short public exponent `e`**, usually 65537 (0x10001). This is true, when **fast exponentiation is used** (method named [Exponentiation_by_squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)). **Time of this operation depends linearly on bit length and  linearly on `1` bits count in exponent's value**, both length and count are small for 65537 (17 bit length and 2 bits are in state `1`).

*In your pseudocode* of RSA-like operation, *`e` is 32 bit* and it **is** usually **shorter than `d`**, therefore operation using `e` exponent is faster than same with `d`.

Comment: Mr osgx. Why you say don't implement RSA yourself? I try study RSA idea by use java.I try to understand the theoretical study and then converted into a practical application.in my program in the above I tested encryption and decryption function  when m(plaintext) = 64 Bits and gave me the correct results.My question to you Is wrong programs?Am I can not calculate time here and then rely on the results and writing in my study?

Comment: @mhsz studying RSA is never wrong, but you definitively should not then try and convert it into a practical application. And you should not need to, you can simply rely on the supplied libraries instead. As said, there are many attacks on RSA. Preventing e.g. side channel attacks that use timing is really hard.

Comment: @mhsz, Sure, you can study RSA by implementing it, but you should not use you implementations in real products, because your implementation is vulnerable (easy to crack/hack). Real (commercial) RSA implementations are huge and made by experienced people with cryptographic education. Crypto lecturer, [Dan Boneh (Stanford)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Boneh) says "Don't implement crypto yourself". And, please, read the real books about RSA when studying it, e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=q35DEvUTkH0C esp. chapt. 6 or Handbook of Applied Cryptography or Applied Cryptography or PKCS#1.

Comment: ok thank you for all, somebody give me method to Measurement and prove decrept  executetime slower than encrypt executetime  in RSA cryptography. or this stay secret!

Comment: @mhsz, Should I mark the answer with bold? Encryption using `e` is faster than decryption using `d`, because `e` is smaller than `d`. This is true both in case of classic RSA, when e is equal to 0x3 or 0x101, and in your code (most 32 bit `e` and longer `d`). Java's `modPow` probably uses "Exponentiation by squaring" method, which is faster for smaller numbers.